# JavaScript: Variables not working outside function?

Tags: javascript, json

Why cannot I call variables that I have defined inside a function? This is my code...

```
  var username;
  var rank;
  var steamid;
  var avatar;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        if (this.responseText == "null") {
        } else {
            var infoArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var username = infoArr.username;
            var rank = infoArr.rank;
            var steamid = infoArr.steamid;
            var avatar = infoArr.avatar;
            testIt();
      }
    }
};

xhr.open("GET", "../getInfo.php", true);
xhr.send();

function testIt() {
  alert(username);
}
```

Function testIt() is returning: undefined

What my code does is to get info from a JSON encoded page and make variables.

Comment: Inside your callback function you are setting the scope on those variables to local by using `var`.  Remove var from in front of username, rank, steamid, avatar, in the callback function.

Comment: I mean... of course it doesn't work. `testIt` has no access to that variable. You should either pass it to `testIt` or just remove `testIt` and move that logic into the callback. Don't move to global variables by removing `var`...

Comment: Thanks for answering. Solved now :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the variables outside of the function, they need to be defined outside of the function.

```
var username, rank, steamid, avatar, infoArr, username, rank, steamid, avatar;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        if (this.responseText == "null") {
        } else {
            infoArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            username = infoArr.username;
            rank = infoArr.rank;
            steamid = infoArr.steamid;
            avatar = infoArr.avatar;
            testIt();
      }
    }
};

xhr.open("GET", "../getInfo.php", true);
xhr.send();

function testIt() {
  alert(username);
}
```